# CSS :FirstChild in same section with 2 class not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

Color is not applied as per CSS on the 3rd row, using first child(div.multiple-alerts .normal:first-child span).

https://jsfiddle.net/Lh6cpzeb/

```css
div.multiple-alerts .high:first-child span{ color: yellow; }

div.multiple-alerts .normal:first-child span{ color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="multiple-alerts">
  <div class="cls high"><span>high</span></div>
  <div class="cls high"><span>high</span></div>
  <div class="cls normal"><span>normal</span></div>
  <div class="cls normal"><span>normal</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: wrong use of first-child.  first-child represents the very first child of a parent.  Not first child that has a particular class.  Good answer here on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Answer (score 1):

The CSS is being applied the correct way, but I think your understanding of how the rules work may be slightly off. You're selecting the first child of all `div`s with class `multiple-alerts` which also has the class of `normal`. Well, the first child of `multiple-alerts` does not have the class `normal` (at least in the snippet you included), so your selector matches exactly zero elements.

Now, you may be tempted to go for something like `first-of-type`, but that only applies to tags, not classes. So, here's a workaround that you might find useful:

Let's say the standard colour for these `span`s is black, we will set all the `span`s inside `.normal` with yellow colour, then override it for all but the first one, like so:

```
div.multiple-alerts .normal span {
  color: yellow;
}
div.multiple-alerts .normal ~ .normal span {
  color: black;
}
```

If you're not sure how this is working here, the `~` works similarly to the `+`, but is broader. The `+` can only match with the very next sibling, whereas the `~` can match with *any succeeding* sibling - i.e. after, but not before.

Answer (score 1):

`:nth-child(i)` selector will solve the problem

```
div.multiple-alerts .cls:nth-child(3) span{ color: yellow; }
```